# Eclipse 3.7 formatting static in class

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

In Eclipse 3.7 is code:

```
public class AppResources
{
    private static Image titleIcon;
    static
    {
        AppResources.titleIcon = getIconImage();
    }

    public static Image getTitleIcon()
    {
        return AppResources.titleIcon;
    }
}
```

Where in Formatter is possible to say that before `static` should be empty line?

Comment: I don't think that's  possible. I think Eclipse recognize the static block as a variable.

Comment: I can format variables with one empty line between them, it's in Window -> Preferences -> Formatter -> Edit -> Blank Lines -> Before field declaration. Problem is it's "before" not "after".

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate formatting setting for the static block.  For formatting purposes it appears to be treated as any other member variable (as opposed to a function or some other construct).

There is another way to end up with the formatting you want though.  If you set the formatting option Blank Lines->Existing Blank Lines->Number of empty lines to preserve to be 1, then you can manually add a blank line before the static block and the formatter will not remove it.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but not possible for my needs. i have lots of the code which have empty lines which should be removed, no empty line to preserve.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the most targeted at your problem the standard formatter can get...  Good luck.

Comment: we have tons of gui code which after generated by gui builder we modyfied. if we check "lines to preserve" than we will need to manual format code. has found [article](www.eclipse.org/imp/documents/impFormattingHowto.pdf) on eclipse formatter, trying to understood.

Comment: Is your generated code in a different project than your static{} block?  If so, you could use per-project formatting: UI project has 0 for lines to preserve, everyone else has 1.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers point out, this is not possible to do for `static` blocks through the Eclipse formatter. One other way to accomplish this would be through search/replace in `File Search` in Eclipse:

From:

```
(^\s*\n)*(^\s*static\s*\{)
```

To:

```
\n\2
```

with `Regular Expression` enabled

Comment: Problem with that I think is that the next time they format their code, the extra newline will get blown away!

Comment: @Alex after next ctrl-shift-f it will go left :-) has been looking for solution through eclipse formatter, looks it's not possible. have to rewrite eclipse formatter :-)

Comment: yes, this "formatting" will be reset when the actual Eclipse formatter is invoked. To avoid that, you could enable `@formatter:off` and `@formatter:on` in the Eclipse formatter and use that in code. Not an elegant solution by a long shot.